# Returning mysql rows depending on multiple different values

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have table which contains information of my users and have these attributes: `name`, `surname` and `date_of_birth`. I want to return rows that have different `name` and different `surname` and different `date_of_birth`. I know that query goes something like `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`.

Here is an example

```
   USERS

id | name     | surname   | date_of_birth
---+----------+-----------+-----------
1  | Mark     | Smith     | 01.01.1990.
2  | Ana      | Smith2    | 01.01.1991.
3  | Ana      | Smith2    | 01.01.1991.
4  | Mark     | Smith2    | 01.01.1991.

  RESULT

id | name     | surname   | date_of_birth
---+----------+-----------+-----------
1  | Mark     | Smith     | 01.01.1990.
3  | Ana      | Smith2    | 01.01.1991.
4  | Mark     | Smith2    | 01.01.1991.
```

Row has to have different value in all three attributes to be selected as a result.

Comment: I think `SELECT DISTINCT name, surname, date_of_birth FROM table` should be all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` to eliminate duplicate rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
     , surname
     , date_of_birth
FROM USERS
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `SELECT` everything, except `id`, then you can use `DISTINCT` keyword in your `SELECT`, just like *@Rocket Hazmat* has suggested:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `name`
     , `surname`
     , `date_of_birth` 
FROM `table`
```

But if you also want to display the first (*earliest, minimum*) `id` between all duplicate values (*as you have illustrated in your example*), then you should use the following query :

```
SELECT MIN(`id`)
     , `name`
     , `surname`
     , `date_of_birth`
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `name`
       , `surname`
       , `date_of_birth`
```